# How to click item on first form while having another form open

Tags: c#, forms

Example image:
[image]

I just want to know how to click something on the parent form while the child is active!

Why I want it: Users may need to access one dialog while looking at another.

Comment: Dont make the child modal?

Comment: Pass the mainForm instance to your childform. Create a event in your childform. The mainform can subscribe than.

Comment: What are you trying to say, can you find and example and link me?

Comment: Try to understand what i said by googleing any word what you do not understand.

Comment: Yes thank you all, not making it a modal worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying a form with call:

```
new Form2().showDialog();
```

Will not allows you to click on the `form1`.

```
new Form2().show();
```

Will allow you to click parent `form1`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested by [David Pilkington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732806/david-pilkington).

I fixed it by going from:

```
form.ShowDialog(this);
```

to:

```
form.Show(this);
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

quite simply (re-factored) you can use this.

```
//Open as dialog
new Form2().showDialog();
//Open as new instance
f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
```